# Modifying UVC driver for a second camera

Tags: kernel, camera

I am trying to modify the UVC driver (uvc_video.c) to enable a second camera on my system (Jetson Xavier NX). I have two 1080p 60fps cameras, and the second camera's activation always results in failure, presumably due to running out of USB bandwidth. Both cameras are USB 3.0, and the USB controller on the Xavier NX is also 3.0. The cameras support both compressed and uncompressed formats, and there is no way they actually need the full 5Gbps of bandwidth to show a picture. I am modifying the driver and recompiling the kernel in order to circumvent the issue.

My question is about the meaning of the `ctrl->dwMaxPayloadTransferSize` variable in the uvc_video.c file. I'm assuming it should be set in bytes, and I believed it's the bytes per second given to each camera, but I've used various values already without fixing my camera issue, and without any change at all in fact. If the variable is the bandwidth, setting it to a low enough value should prevent either camera from working or, if one camera starts up, allow a second camera to work as well since it won't saturate the USB controller. But I still get one camera working, and the second freezing both feeds when started. Am I missing something? What exactly should `ctrl->dwMaxPayloadTransferSize` be set to, at least approximately, assuming my system and camera parameters?